# Get keycode regardless of keyboard layout

Tags: javascript, qt, qtwebkit

I have a program in which I need to get the keycode in javascript of a pressed key no matter what keyboard language settings a user has.

This is my code:

JS:

```
window.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    console.log(e.keyCode);
    // it works fine in all browsers, but in qwebview keycode == 0 in russian layout
});
```

Python:

```
class View(QWebView):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(QWebView, self).__init__(parent)

    def keyPressEvent(self, e):
        print e.key() # same as in JS
        print e.nativeScanCode() # ??
        # QWebView.keyPressEvent(self, e)
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `e.code` property instead of `e.keyCode`. For instance, pressing the first letter key on either an American or French keyboard (on French, it is an A) will give you `KeyQ`.

Note that it doesn't work on Edge. Tested on version 18, as of April 2019.

Use this website to test it: http://keycode.info

Comment: Good suggestion about using `e.code` instead, but support for `e.key` is slightly better in older browsers, so that might be prefered if dealing with IE/Edge. Also, take a look at https://keys.dev 

Comment: `e.key` is better supported, but does not meet this requirement: "no matter what keyboard language settings a user has". An itermediate solution may be `console.log(e.code || e.key)` (try `e.code`, falling back to `e.key` if necessary - remembering that `code` is a string like `'Semicolon'` and `key` is a string like `'ç'`).

Answer (score 0):

Both `e.which` and `e.keyCode` are deprecated, so you should be using `e.key` or `e.code` instead:

- [`e.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key):

  > The `KeyboardEvent` interface's `key` read-only property returns the value of the key pressed by the user, taking into consideration the state of modifier keys such as <kbd>Shift</kbd> as well as the keyboard locale and layout. Its value is determined as follows:
- [`e.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code):

  > The `KeyboardEvent.code` property represents a physical key on the keyboard (as opposed to the character generated by pressing the key). In other words, this property returns a value that isn't altered by keyboard layout or the state of the modifier keys.

[Support for `e.key` is slightly better in older browsers](https://caniuse.com/keyboardevent-key), so this one will work on some old versions of Edge and IE. Just keep in mind some of these old browsers used non-standard codes, so, for example, left is usually `'LeftArrow'` and right is `'RightArrow'`, but on IE it's just `'Left'` and `'Right'` instead.

Also, if you need to check KeyboardEvent's properties values such as `e.key`, `e.code`, `e.which` or `e.keyCode` you can use https://keyjs.dev. I will add information about these kinds of cross-browser incompatibilities soon!

[image: Key.js \ JavaScript KeyboardEvent's key codes & key identifiers]

**Disclaimer: I'm the author.**